# How to send HTTP response 200 OK with body?

Tags: php, http

I have implemented a webhook receiver for a payment gateway and on receiving a successful payment event I need to reply with the status 200 ok with the body "{ success: true }".

This is what I have in my code, but how do I send the body?

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Comment: you can send code in the body you have to manually add it to response body`{ success: true, code: 200}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just echo "{ success: true }"; 200 OK should be emitted by default, how about an unsuccessful payment? what do you need to send then.

Comment: Thanks, Paun, this is the URL https://www.notion.so/Merchant-API-Integration-Guide-22899fe142fe42508c40336d13e7164b and they don't ask to send anything for an unsuccessful payment.